# Existance (of lack thereof) of minimizers of the area functional on $A_M=\{u\in C(\bar{A})\cap C^1(A):u=0 \; if\; x=2 \; u=M \;if \; x=1\}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

I was trying to find to find the minimizer of the area functional
$$F(u)=\int_A \sqrt{1+|\nabla u(x)|^2}dx $$
where $A=\{A=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2: 1<|x|<2\}\}$ with the solution belonging to the set
$\mathcal{A}_{M}=\{u\in C(\bar{A})\cap C^1(A):u=0 \text{ on } |x| \text{ and } u=M \text{ on } |x|=1\}$.

I actually want to prove that for $M>M_0$ the problem has no solution.

It all came to prove that for the minimizer u we need to have $u(x)=\varphi|x|=\varphi(r)$, id est the minimizer is radial, and the  EL equation associated with the problem is 
$$\frac{d}{dr}\left(\frac{r\varphi'}{\sqrt{1+\varphi'^2}}\right)=0 $$ but now I'm stuck since I don't know how to solve this.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can explicitate the function $\varphi(r)$
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{d}{dr}\left(\frac{r\varphi'}{\sqrt{1+\varphi'^2}}\right)&=0\\
\implies \frac{r\varphi'}{\sqrt{1+\varphi'^2}} &=c\\
\implies r^2\varphi'^2 & =c^2+c^2\varphi'^2\\
\implies \varphi'&=\frac{c}{\sqrt{r^2-c^2}}\\
\implies \varphi &=c \ln\left(\left|\frac{\sqrt{r^2-c^2}+r}{c}\right|\right)+d.
\end{split}$$
We can now impose the boundary condition
$$
\begin{split}
0= \varphi(2)&=c \ln\left(\left|\frac{\sqrt{4-c^2}+2}{c}\right|\right)+d\\
\implies d&=-c ln\left(\left|\frac{\sqrt{4-c^2}+2}{c}\right|\right)\\
M  =\varphi(1) &=c \ln\left(\left|\frac{\sqrt{1-c^2}+1}{c}\right|\right)-c \ln\left(\left|\frac{\sqrt{1-c^2}+1}{c}\right|\right)\\
\implies M &=c \ln\left(\left|\frac{\sqrt{1-c^2}+1}{\sqrt{4-c^2}+2}\right|\right)
\end{split}
$$
Now we notice that for the function to be real valued we need $|c|\le 1$
and so we can conclude that for the solution to exist the following inequality has to be satisfied 
$$ \inf_{c\in[-1,1]}c \ln\left(\left|\frac{\sqrt{1-c^2}+1}{\sqrt{4-c^2}+2}\right|\right)\le M\le \sup_{c\in[-1,1]}c \ln\left(\left|\frac{\sqrt{1-c^2}+1}{\sqrt{4-c^2}+2}\right|\right)$$ but actually since $c \ln\left(\left|\frac{\sqrt{1-c^2}+1}{\sqrt{4-c^2}+2}\right|\right)$ in regards of the variable $c$ is in $C([-1,1])$ we have that the minimum and maximum are attained (and so they are finite) and so we can write 
 $$ \min_{[-1,1]}c \ln\left(\left|\frac{\sqrt{1-c^2}+1}{\sqrt{4-c^2}+2}\right|\right)\le M\le \max_{[-1,1]}c \ln\left(\left|\frac{\sqrt{1-c^2}+1}{\sqrt{4-c^2}+2}\right|\right).$$

So if $M$ is outside this interval then the minimum problem for the area functional has no solution.